# Does automorphism preserve the quotient of groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ and $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ be the automorphism group of $G$.

Is there any example that $G/N$ is not isomorphic to $G/\gamma(N)$ for some $\gamma\in \mathrm{Aut}(G)$ ?

Comment: No. non όχι (I have to type a minimal number of characters!)

Comment: @Bernard: Are you sure ?

Comment: Well, if $\varphi$ is the automorphism, $gN\mapsto \varphi(g)\varphi(N)$ is the isomorphism of $G/N$ onto $G/\varphi(N)$.

Comment: @Bernard: The problem is that the map is not well defined. (take different repsesentative)

Comment: @Bernard: Actually I am not sure. today I worıked a lt :)

Comment: For me it *is* well defined: if $g^{-1}g'\in N$, $\varphi(g^{-1})\varphi(g')\in \varphi(N)$. Where is the problem?

Comment: @mesel It is well defined.  If xN = yN then the images are also equal.

Comment: @Bernard: I guess you are right. I had thougt that it is not well defined :(. Thanks.

Comment: @mesel: we all work too much… :o)

Comment: @Bernard: :))))))))))))))))) (To have  a minimal number of characters)

Comment: I prefer Greek. Προτιμώ Ελληνικά.

Comment: @Bernard: Bender τουρκική. Bende Türkçe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$G / N$ is isomorphic to $G / \gamma(N)$ for any automorphism $\gamma$.  The reason is that an automorphism $\gamma$ lifts to an isomorphism $\hat \gamma : G / N \rightarrow G / \gamma (N)$ where $\hat \gamma(x N) = \gamma (x) \gamma (N)$.